# Looking for a source on the city of Gilad

Tags: sources-mekorot, slave-serve-eved-avadim

Some time ago I heard a Dvar Torah (which I brought [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/110990/20472)) by someone who stated, among other things, that the city of Gilad used to be, at least from the time of the sale of Yosef until it was conquered by the Tribe of Menashe, a center for slave-trafficking. I don't remember if a source for this was brought. Does anyone know any source on the matter?

Comment: Maybe related to [בגלעד שכיחי רוצחים](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Makkot.9b.19?lang=bi)?

Comment: I thought Gilad was/is the name of a region, not a city.

Comment: @TamirEvan I think it may have been both, but אין הכי נמי, either way, it was presented in the Dvar Torah as some sort of populated area that dealt in slave-trafficking.

Comment: @ba maybe, though, I don't quite see how one gets from murderers to slave-traffickers. There might be something in "לא תגנוב" which is short for "לא תגנוב את הנפש", which means don't kidnap people, though the term sounds a bit like murder (stealing a soul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, the person who gave over the dvar Torah wrote down all of it [here](https://www.biu.ac.il/sites/default/files/inline-files/dvarim_givon.pdf). It seems that it should be inferred that Gilad was a place of slave-trafficking because the Yishmaelim *came from there* and they were obviously slavers, because both the brothers thought to sell Yosef to them upon seeing them and the Yishmaelim themselves immediately agreed to the sale when it was offered to them.